# Is it possible to clear MPMediaItemCollection using codes?

Tags: iphone

I store all audios to a MPMediaItemCollection. Later, I hope to clear all items in the MpMediaItemCollection.
Is it possible to clear MPMediaItemCollection using codes?

Thanks
interdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the "codes" are, but if you mean programmatically, then I'm afraid the answer is no. `MPMediaItemCollection` is usually the result of querying the iPod library on its content. If you use it to store your own lists then my first guess is you are doing something wrong.